# Prove that for a subgroup $G$ of $S_{13}$, each element can be written as a product of $\sigma^i$ and $\tau^j$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Given that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_{13}$ (symmetric group) which can be generated with the following two permutations, how can I prove that every element in $G$ can be written as a product of $\sigma$s and $\tau$s?

$$\sigma = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )( 6, 10 )( 7, 11 )( 8, 12 )( 9, 13 ),$$

$$\tau = ( 2, 5 )( 3, 4 )( 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 )$$

My attempt:

Find orders of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ : $10$ and $8$ respectively (using lcm).

Then also, $G$ is not abelian since $\tau^{-1} \sigma \tau \neq \sigma$.

$\tau^{-1} \sigma \tau = \sigma^{-1}$ implies that $\tau \sigma = \sigma^{-1} \tau = \sigma^{9} \tau$

letting $0 \leq i \leq 9$ and $0 \leq j \leq 7$, we get the product of the form $\sigma^i \tau^j$.

I am not sure if I have actually proved what I needed to. Would really appreciate some help on making sure the proof is correct. Thank you!

Comment: What is your definition of “generated by?” Because “subgroup generated by $\sigma,\tau$ is pretty much defined as “subgroup composed of products of  $\sigma, \tau.$ On the other hand, your title implies you want the elements to be of the form $\sigma^i\tau^j$ which is a subset of all products.

Comment: Did you mean $\sigma^{-1}\tau=\sigma^9\tau?$ Because $-9$ is wrong.

Comment: Sorry I think I meant that G is the subgroup where all of its elements are products of  and  but I want to show that there exist integers i and j such that any element can be written as a product of ^^ .

Comment: It must be a pain to type things up without $\rm\LaTeX$. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: It will help to note $\sigma^5=\tau^4$.

Comment: It’s not clear how $\tau^{~1}\sigma\tau\neq \sigma$ implies the equality you say it implies. The equality might be true, but it is hard to see how the inequality implies it.

Comment: And $\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau=\sigma^{-1}$ complete it.

Comment: I agree with @ThomasAndrews, you need to establish the equality by pure calculation. $G$ has order 40 by the way.

Comment: Sorry I have made the edits to my question. I am not sure how to actually prove the question.

Comment: Sorry how did you figure out the size of $G$? @ancientmathematician

Comment: @corgilover123 : from the two identities I have given in my comments there are at most $40$ distinct elements. And I can see a cyclic group of order $20$ which is not the whole group, namely $\langle \sigma^2, \tau^2\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

You have there an anti-commutativity relation: $ \sigma\tau=\tau\sigma^9 $ (note that I corrected it).  Since $\sigma $ and  $\tau $ generate,  every element of the group can be written as a *word* in $\sigma $ and $\tau $.

Then the anti-commutativity relation allows you to rewrite those words into the form $\sigma^i\tau^j $  (thus the order is at most $80$).