# Find order of group $G$ given that it is generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

$$\sigma = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ) ( 6, 10 ) ( 7, 11 ) ( 8, 12 ) ( 9, 13 )$$

$$\tau = ( 2, 5 ) ( 3, 4 ) ( 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 )$$

I know that the orders of these permutations are 10 and 8 respectively.

$$H = \langle \sigma \rangle$$

$$K = \langle \tau \rangle$$

Are $H$ and $K$ subgroups of $G$?

Given that $G$ is generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$, and that $\langle H\cap K \rangle$ has order 2 (contains elements () and $( 6, 10 )( 7, 11 )(8, 12)(9, 13)$ ), how do I figure out the size of $G$?

Thank you for all of the help.

Comment: Hint: The both permutations permute the elements $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and the elements $\{6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13\}$ separately, this is likely to make everything simpler.

Answer (score 4):

From the solution to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4093030/prove-that-for-a-subgroup-g-of-s-13-each-element-can-be-written-as-a-prod?noredirect=1#comment8460100_4093030)
we know that every element of $G$ is of the form $\sigma^i \tau^j$ with $0\leqslant i <10$, $0\leqslant j<8$.

We also notice that $\sigma^5=\tau^4$, so we now know that every element of $G$ is of the form $\sigma^i \tau^j$ with $0\leqslant i <10$, $0\leqslant j<4$.

That is, $G$ has order at most $40$.

Now $G$ has a subgroup $\langle \sigma^2, \tau^2\rangle=\langle (1\ 3\ 5\ 2\ 4), (6\ 8\ 10\ 12)(7\ 9\ 11\ 13)\rangle$ which is visibly abelian of order $5\cdot 4 =20$.

Moreover $G$ itself is  not abelian as $\sigma$ and $\tau$ do not commute. So $|G|=40$.

Comment: I like this approach (+1).

Comment: Thank you. I understand everything except why we then have 0 < j < 4 in the second line.

Comment: But @corgilover123 surely it's clear that we can replace $\sigma^i \tau^j$  when $j\geqslant 4$, by $\sigma^{i+5}\tau^{j-4}$, and then reduce $i+5$ modulo $10$?